# Two different results Google maps in Android

Tags: android, maps

I want to open Google Maps and there i want to mark 2 different places.

Is this possible?

i try to avoid my own Googlemaps View...

Thanks for your answers.

Prexx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Throwing parameters at maps.google.com only gets you one point.
>
> As dusoft says, you could use Google Static maps.
>
> Or, if you require dynamic maps, you could write your own public web
>   page that uses Google Maps API and accepts a long list of parameters.
>   Use your own web page in exactly the same way that you were intending
>   to use maps.google.com web page, except that you get to design what
>   you want the parameters to look like.
>
> Perhaps something like this.

[URL for multiple markers in Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771879/url-for-multiple-markers-in-google-maps)

The same applies for Google Maps app in Android I guess, since the Intents are not well documented. The only way you can get Maps to open what you want is through `geo://` urls which is essentially the same as urls to maps.google.com.

Comment: Then i have to implement my own Mapsview... thank you anyway!