# kmz in google maps with dynamic lat long?

Tags: html, google-maps, kml, kmz

I'm using google maps under my google account to load a kmz file which is good and working, but I want to load a new pin marker by manipulating the header url. So far I've tried q=lat,long which loads the marker, but it doesn't maintain the kmz polygons and info. It simply loads a green arrow (my coordinates) but does so on the plain grey google map.

Does anyone have any idea how to load the marker but still keep the kmz data on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible without using the API / JavaScript. Reading through the available query string parameters, there are none which allow you to specify a kml/kmz input file separate from just the q= query string variable. It looks like the staticmaps ( [URL for multiple markers in Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771879/url-for-multiple-markers-in-google-maps) ) feature may include the ability for multiple markers though if this could serve your purpose. you will need to pass the KML as part of the query string though, something like:

`?q=http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/KML_Samples.kml&markers=-134,68,0`

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Mathew. I appreciate your help. I ended up revisiting the api route.