# Can I create a url that opens a google map with 3 points on it (A, B, C) with my defined coordinates?

Tags: google-maps

can I make a url that shows a google map with 3 or more points? something like `https://maps.google.com/maps?q=58+41.881N+152+31.324W` ([link](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=58+41.881N+152+31.324W)) but with more points.

possible?

Comment: How is this related to a programming?

Comment: because I need it for python, so I can open a browserwindow with the points inside

Comment: possible duplicate of [URL for multiple markers in Google Maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771879/url-for-multiple-markers-in-google-maps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible to specify multiple markers in the URL to [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com).

Other options:

1. create a KML file containing the points, then pass that to Google Maps in the URL [example](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http%3a%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2Fkmltest_2_SUNSHINE_CHEVRON_b_kml.xml&hl=en&sll=25.641526,-79.101562&sspn=23.171946,41.52832&t=m&z=15)
2. use a [static map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/)

Comment: According to [KML files on Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/support/kmlmaps), from February 2015, Google Maps will no longer load KML/KMZ files from external websites.