# Google Maps Query Parameters to show more than one marker

Tags: google-maps

How can I set query part of my url to load more than one marker in Google Map.
with following I can load one marker.

http://maps.google.com/maps?q=40.01696,32.33076&z=17.

I need some thing like following query, but not for static map!

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/map?center=46.525510999999995,6.562825000000001&size=300x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue|label:You|46.525510999999995,6.562825000000001&markers=color:green|label:A|46.525876,6.561572&markers=color:green|label:B|46.524586,6.564591&markers=color:green|label:C|46.523745,6.560512&markers=color:green|label:D|46.52486,6.563096&markers=color:green|label:E|46.524678,6.563687&sensor=true&language=en

Comment: You have this tagged [google-maps-api-3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-3); you can create as many markers as you want on your own API based map.  Are you looking for an [embedded map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/)?

Comment: maybe I make mistake, I want to load map with more than one marker in  browser window.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I create a url that opens a google map with 3 points on it (A, B, C) with my defined coordinates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820713/can-i-create-a-url-that-opens-a-google-map-with-3-points-on-it-a-b-c-with-my)

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not possible. In my opinion you have 2 choices:

1. Use a static Map
2. Use Google Maps with your .kml file to specify the markers.

Description from Google:

https://support.google.com/mapsengine/answer/2505884?hl=en

There is a example here:

https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http%3a%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2Fkmltest_2_SUNSHINE_CHEVRON_b_kml.xml&hl=en&sll=25.641526,-79.101562&sspn=23.171946,41.52832&t=m&z=15

Comment: duplicate answer to [Can I create a url that opens a google map with 3 points on it (A, B, C) with my defined coordinates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820713/can-i-create-a-url-that-opens-a-google-map-with-3-points-on-it-a-b-c-with-my/15822167#15822167)