# Google map: "click to see this area on google maps" - how to keep the markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My website has a map with a marker on it (pointing to a specific business address)

At the bottom left corner of the map is a Google sign which says:

"Click to see this area on Google maps"

When I click the Google sign, it opens a larger map in a new window.
However, the marker is not there.  (it doesn't make sense!)

Is there any way to keep the marker when clicking to view on a larger map ?

Many thanks!!
[image]

Comment: Never used jsfiddle. I'll try to set this up. meanwhile i added a screenshot of the link I'm referring to.

Comment: Don't have to, I already see it now - the icon is pretty dim! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite obvious - why would maps.google.com show markers in your application? They just say: "click to see this **area**" - so it just to see that **area** on a different map..

If you need a direct link to maps.google.com which will create the markers, look here: [URL for multiple markers in Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1771879/684229)

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Every map has this Google sign. Is there any way to implement this then? If not on by clicking in the Goolgle sign, then in a separate link, which will open a larger map and still have the marker.  Thanks.