# Google Map to show markers for multiple location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

What I am trying to do is using Google map URL `(https://maps.google.com/maps)` ,I want to have markers for multiple location also I don't want to use Google Map API.

I am only able to get a marker for single location using

https://maps.google.com/maps?q=22.96783,88.74398

is there something like `https://maps.google.com/maps?q=22.96783,88.74398&22.99783,88.78398` to get markers for multiple location (though it is not working in this format)

Any reference or help will be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [URL for multiple markers in Google Maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771879/url-for-multiple-markers-in-google-maps)

Answer (score 1):

Heres what you want -- basically the url string can hold more than one marker / location details.  I've used the static version before on a project but heres the functional map version example I'd start with:

url syntax:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=14&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue|label:S|40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green|label:G|40.711614,-74.012318&markers=color:red|color:red|label:C|40.718217,-73.998284&sensor=false
```

[example here](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn%20Bridge,New%20York,NY&zoom=14&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap&markers=color%3ablue%7Clabel%3aS%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color%3agreen%7Clabel%3aG%7C40.711614,-74.012318&markers=color%3ared%7Ccolor%3ared%7Clabel%3aC%7C40.718217,-73.998284&sensor=false)

(note: if will have heavy use you should obtain a key and add this to the end of the URL:

```
&key=YOUR_MAPS_API_KEY
```

)

Comment: Thanks tamak for your response, I am not looking for static map,my requirement is of Google map with multiple marker. can It be possible without using Google Map API?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a custom google map to show multiple locations (not multiple destinations), without API, but the capability is limited.  The locations are input by either searching and selecting the locations individually or by inporting a csv or xlsx.

I did it from chrome (logged in) with the google maps app installed.  Open the app and click the search bar, you should see something that states "my custom maps"  click and from there it is pretty straight forward.  One created send out the map link.  You are limited to 3 layers in free version.

Comment: How do you combine multiple searched locations into a single query? Is that possible? Can you provide code?

Answer (score 0):

the csv file you upload can contain multiple locations; all it needs to be easily imported is the first row with column headers, and then subsequent rows can have label, lat, long.